# Entering the EU with insurance info on cellphone

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, insurance, sweden, mexican-citizens

My question concerns entering EU via Sweden to get to Helsinki, I have given all the documents (invitation, contract of my house, bank account, etc.) to my friend. She has printed all of them. I have also bought a ticket to London to get out of the Schengen area, but the insurance is not printed; she has it in her phone to display.
Could there be problems with Swedish customs since that is not on paper but on her cellphone?

EDIT: Sorry I misspoke; as Mexicans, we do not require visas to enter the EU, but the Schengen area asks for insurance.

EDIT2: I want to wait until it has passed to see who got the correct answer :)

Comment: What's her citizenship? If she has a visa, she had to submit proof of insurance when applying but it's unlikely to be checked again at the border, see e.g. http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13405/do-i-need-to-have-travel-insurance-when-crossing-schengen-border If she does not need one, insurance is not needed either, see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/33864/documents-necessary-and-recommended-for-first-time-travel-to-eu-for-us-citizen/33868#33868 In any case, it's unlikely to be a problem.

Comment: Mexican, like we have 90 days of schengen visa.

Comment: @Relaxed - But they do ask you to carry copies of the documents, provided with the visa application, with you always in the Schengen region. They give you a slip mentioning so. But in the past 5 years, I have never been asked to furnish even once.

Comment: @Pedro.Alonso Mexican citizens can enter the Schengen area for 90 days *without visa*. Legally, it makes a difference. People who really do need a visa have to apply in advance and submit a lot of things to a consulate to get one. They can't just show up at the border.

Comment: @DumbCoder Indeed, which is why I made a distinction. To repeat: If you don't need a visa, insurance is not required. If you do need a visa, insurance is also required but unlikely to be checked in practice.

Comment: @Pedro.Alonso I thought insurance was required as well until a few months ago but this requirement is nowhere to be found in the Borders Code (it's part of the requirements for visas). What makes you believe that insurance is required?

Comment: In the Mexican web it states that to travel to EU you need money, a person there and insurance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could there be a problems with Swedish customs, if that is not in paper, is on her cellphone?

Chances are she will be just fine. I have travelled without any insurance documents many a times and never been asked to furnish it either at border controls or anywhere while travelling inside the EU (I carry my EHIC card always anyway). If asked anywhere else, I would belive the electonic form should satisfy, if it carries her name and is valid for the period and country she is travelling in.

But as a precaution it would be better she carries one whenever possible.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that she is on the US traveling in the airports, she has not found a printer, so I do not know where can she find one.

Comment: No need to search for a printer. She can go ahead with her travel. And if stopped ask her to use her tear ducts to good avail. But I would believe the insurance on her mobile should satisfy them.

Comment: Haha, ok I'll let her know :)

Answer (score 1):

As Mexican citizen, she doesn't need to apply for a visa and therefore does not need insurance. While a return ticket is not formally required, it's certainly useful to be able to show one. Border guards can ask her to produce other supporting documents but most of the time they don't do it.

See also [Documents necessary (and recommended) for first time travel to EU for US Citizen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/33864/documents-necessary-and-recommended-for-first-time-travel-to-eu-for-us-citizen)